# Using cat to write a file containing bash commands

Tags: bash, cat

Consider the following bash scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF > file
$@
VAR=`cat somefile`
EOF
```

I want to write a file called `file` such that `$@` is evaluated but `cat something` is not. In other words I want the output to look like this:

```
Arg1 Arg2 Arg3 Arg4 
VAR=`cat something`
```

If I use `'EOF'` instead of `EOF`, then nothing gets evaluated, but I want `$@` to be evaluated.

Comment: You have then to escape the characters which you don't want to be treated as expansion. If this is too tedious (if the content of the here-doc is large), you may consider putting `file` together with more than one invocation of `cat`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried escaping the characters? Using "\`":

```bash
cat <<EOF > file
$@
VAR=\`cat testfile\`
echo \$VAR
> EOF
```

Here is the file content:

```bash
cat file

VAR=`cat testfile`
echo $VAR
```

Then execute it:

```bash
./file
Hi!
```

Comment: You probably also need a `chmod +x file` before you can execute it as `./file`.

Comment: Didn't add it becuase it's out of the scope for the question.

Comment: Showing how to execute the the resulting `file` is also out of the scope of the question, but you included that in your answer.  That's why I thought you should mention the `chmod` too, for completeness.